# Add a column from an excel file to another one with python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have 2 equals excel file, the exception is on one column in less in one of them
I need to grab the value from the first file and paste on the other one
I use pandas to do that but I can't  do it

After read the excel file and sved them into a variable I do:

**df_foglio1 = pd.read_excel(excel_file, sheet_name, header=0)**

**df_backup = pd.read_excel(backup, sheet_name, header=0)**

So I want to grab the first column from **df_foglio1** and put it like first column in **df_backup**

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the following way,

```
df_backup['column_name'] = df_foglio1['first_column_name']
```

Answer (score 0):

This does what you are asking for.

```
df_foglio1 = pd.read_excel(excel_file, sheet_name, header=0)
df_foglio1['first_column_name'].to_excel('df_backup.xslx')
```

Check this out for more implementation details: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html